# Show time with the different hour

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String myTime = "08:00";
    int diffHour = 2;
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date d = df.parse(myTime);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(d);

    for (int i=0; i<=diffHour; i++) {
            cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, i);
            String newTime = df.format(cal.getTime());
            System.out.println(newTime);      
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
08:00
09:00
11:00
```

I want it to be:

```
08:00
09:00
10:00
```

because in the different two hours only until `10:00` if we started with `08:00`.

Why did the output jump from `10:00` to `11:00`?

Comment: Think: What is the value of `i` in each step of the loop? What is the value of `cal` before calling `cal.add`? What is the result of adding `i` hours to the *current*  value of `cal`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
```

You're adding `i`, which will increase by one on each loop, so for the first it will add zero, then one, and then two. Instead, since you want to add by a concrete number, try instead to add just 1.

Though that does mean you would need to start at `07:00`, the other choice is to put some logic in, but that depends on what you are expecting. Something like this could work:

```
for (int i=0; i<=diffHour; i++) {
    if (i <= 1) {
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, i);
    } else {
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
    }
    String newTime = df.format(cal.getTime());
    System.out.println(newTime);
}
```

[Here's a fiddle of it working](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMNWxyV2tLVVdkUzA)

Comment: @FinnD [Do look at Basil's answer as well, they have some great advice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38454293/833070)

Comment: yah I know, that is also great @Draken

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by Draken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38453389/642706) is correct. You are adding `i` where you should be adding a number one `1`.

## java.time

You are also using old troublesome classes now outmoded by the java.time classes.

### `LocalTime`

The [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class represents a time-of-day-only value without date and without time zone.

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse( "08:00" );
int hours = 2;
LocalTime time = start;
for ( int i = 0 ; i <= hours ; i++ ) {
    String output = time.toString();
    // Set up next loop.
    time = time.plusHours( 1 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    package org.app.temputil;

    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Date;

    public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
            String myTime = "08:00";
            int diffHour = 2;
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            Date d = df.parse(myTime);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(d);

            for (int i = 0; i <= diffHour; i++) {
                cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, i == 0 ? 0 : 1);
                String newTime = df.format(cal.getTime());
                System.out.println("i=[" + i + "], time=" + newTime);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: if this works for you then please close the question by accepting the solution that works for you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the description of your code -

```
for (int i=0; i<=diffHour; i++) {
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, i);
        String newTime = df.format(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println(newTime);
}
```

Here the loop is running for i = 0, 1, 2.

For i = 0, 0 is added to calendar so that value remains same as it was earlier 8.

For i = 1, 1 is added to calendar so the value becomes 8 (earlier value) + 1 = 9

For i = 2, 2 is added to calendar so the value becomes 9 (earlier value) + 2 = 11.

To make it work,

Remove the line - `cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, i);`

Add this line -

```
if (i == 0) {
  cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
} else {
 cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your loop to this

```
for (int i=0; i<=diffHour; i++) {           
    String newTime = df.format(cal.getTime());
    System.out.println(newTime);   
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);   
}
```