# How to add specific hour to stirng time in variable using php?

Tags: php, time

how to show time with the different hour in php. for example, I have 2 variable :

```
$start_hour = "08:00"; 
$different_hour = "1";
```

and I want the output like :

> 08:00
>
> 09:00

actually I want it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38453221/show-time-with-the-different-hour). but how can I implement it in php. thank you.

Comment: Do you want to add 1hour to time?

Comment: Please read [PHP doc about date:time](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) as it seems to answer your question

Comment: `echo date('H:i:i', strtotime("+$different_hour hours", strtotime($start_hour)));`

Comment: actually, not only 1 hour. @SahilGulati

Comment: @FinnD Can you check my post now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert string to timestamp using [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and add one hour to timestamp. Write `+1hour` at the start of string time in function parameter to adding one hour to time. At the end, convert timestamp to time using [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
$start_hour = "08:00";
$different_hour = 1;
$newTime = date("H:i", strtotime("+{$different_hour}hour ".$start_hour));
// or
$newTime = date("H:i", strtotime($start_hour) + ($different_hour*60*60));
```

Check code result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/UjCjm)

Comment: why the output only "09:00". can we make the output is "08:00", "09:00" ?. @Mohammad

Comment: oh I did it. just add looping, check it the code in [demo](https://3v4l.org/vbZYB)